# If $G \times G \cong H \times H$ must $G \cong H$?

Tags: group-theory

If $G$ and $H$ are both groups and $G \times G \cong H \times H$, is it required that $G \cong H$?

Comment: I disagree with the duplicate vote. This is a much more general question. This one is answered in a comment to the answer on the one mentioned as duplicate, but not in any detail.

Comment: My mistake, I've retracted the vote.  For reference, [this is a simpler, but related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27667/finite-abelian-groups-and-isomorphism). @anon thank you for courteously pointing out my error

Comment: To get the information directly here: Arturo remarks on the answer to that question that there is an abelian torsion free (not finitely generated) group $G$, such that $G\oplus G\oplus G\simeq G$ but $G\not\simeq G\oplus G$. So for $H = G\oplus G$, this gives a counterexample.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Can more be said how to find such $G$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Unfortunately, I am just quoting what Arturo wrote the other place. I have no idea how one constructs such a group myself.

Comment: Another proof by Corner is freely available [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1969-75-01/S0002-9904-1969-12150-6/).